# Using AngularJS on Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem using AngularJS on Safari running on Windows 7.

Problem appears on line 11413 in `angular.js`

```
    function consoleLog(type) {
      var console = $window.console || {},
          logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
          hasApply = false;

      // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
      // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
      try {
        hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
      } catch (e) {}

      if (hasApply) {
        return function() {
          var args = [];
          forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
            args.push(formatError(arg));
          });
          return logFn.apply(console, args); <------------- HERE PROBLEM APPEARS
        };
      }
```

**Error:     angular.js:11413setting a property that has only a getter**

Can't find any solution to that in google. Does anybody know how to solve this? Using latest AngularJS v1.3.3

Here is the most simple code causing error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    var g_app = angular.module('cc_app', ['ngRoute']);

    g_app.controller('navigation_controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.templates =
        [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
          { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'} ];
        $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    }]);
</script>
<body ng-app="cc_app" ng-controller="navigation_controller">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
        <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div class="slide-animate-container">
        <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

example is taken from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

It works fine on Chrome, but causes mentioned error on Safari.

BTW: Error is caused by ng-include.

**UPDATE**
It works as soon as I remove jquery.

Comment: Going to need to provide what you're doing in the rest of your app. Try to create a fiddle where the error spits out.

Comment: OK, I'll try to make a non-working sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing ordering of script includes. Looks like a conflict.